# efficiently plot large data sets with pyqtgraph

Tags: python, qt, plot, pyqtgraph, vispy

I'm trying to generate a matrix of scatter plots and histograms with pyqtgraph. The input (x and y values) for each scatter plot are numpy arrays of length greater than 1,000,000. It takes a very long time (>1 min for 2x2 plot matrix) for these plots to be generated (matplotlib is actually faster at generating the same plots). Can you anyone point out what I can do to speed things up? Below is the code I'm using.

Thanks.

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg

def scatter_matrix(data, cols):
    pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
    pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')
    now = pg.ptime.time()

    app = QtGui.QApplication([])

    win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Scater Plot Matrix")
    win.resize(800,600)

    for i, col_i in enumerate(cols):
        for j, col_j in enumerate(cols):
            x = data[col_i]
            y = data[col_j]
            if i == j:
                current_plot = win.addPlot(title="Histogram")
                y,x = np.histogram(x, bins=100)
                curve = pg.PlotCurveItem(x, y, stepMode=True, fillLevel=0, brush=(0, 0, 255, 80))
                current_plot.addItem(curve)
            else:
                current_plot = win.addPlot(title="Scatter plot")
                current_plot.plot(x, y, pen=None, symbol='t', symbolPen=None, symbolSize=10, symbolBrush=(100, 100, 255, 50))
                current_plot.setLabel('left', "{}".format(col_i), units='')
                current_plot.setLabel('bottom', "{}".format(col_j), units='')
                current_plot.setLogMode(x=False, y=False)
        win.nextRow()
    ## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
    import sys
    print "Plot time: %0.2f sec" % (pg.ptime.time()-now)
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        app.exec_()

data = {}
for key in ['a','b']:
    data[key] = np.random.normal(size=(1000000), scale=1e-5)

scatter_matrix(data,['a','b'])
```

After a lot of searching around on the web, I ended up trying a gpu based plotting library, galry. The result was a speed up of greater than 100x! Below is the code. Regardless of this I'd still like to know if there are ways to speed up plotting using pyqtgraph.

```
import numpy as np
from galry import *
import time

class MyPaintManager(PlotPaintManager):
    def initialize(self):
        if self.parent.visual == BarVisual:
            self.add_visual(self.parent.visual, self.parent.x, primitive_type= self.parent.plot_type, color='b')
        elif self.parent.visual == PlotVisual:
            self.add_visual(self.parent.visual, x=self.parent.x, y=self.parent.y, primitive_type= self.parent.plot_type, color='b')

class MyWidget(GalryWidget):
    def initialize(self, x, y, visual, title=None, plot_type=None):
        self.activate_grid = True
        self.show_grid = True

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.visual = visual
        self.plot_type = plot_type
        self.title = title

        self.set_bindings(PlotBindings)
        self.set_companion_classes(
            paint_manager=MyPaintManager,
            interaction_manager=PlotInteractionManager,)
        self.initialize_companion_classes()

def scatter_matrix(df, cols):
    now = time.time()

    class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Window, self).__init__()
            self.initUI()

        def initUI(self):
            vbox = QtGui.QGridLayout()
            self.setLayout(vbox)
            self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 600)
            for i, col_i in enumerate(cols):
                for j, col_j in enumerate(cols):
                    x = df[col_i]
                    y = df[col_j]
                    if i == j:
                        y,x = np.histogram(x, bins=100)
                        vbox.addWidget(MyWidget(x=y,y=y, visual = BarVisual, title='{}_vs_{}'.format(col_i, col_j)), i, j)
                    else:
                        vbox.addWidget(MyWidget(x=x,y=y, visual = PlotVisual, title='{}_vs_{}'.format(col_i, col_j), plot_type='POINTS'), i, j)

            print "Plot time: %0.2f sec" % (time.time()-now)
            self.show()

    show_window(Window)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = {}
    for key in ['a','b']:
        data[key] = np.random.normal(size=(1000000), scale=1e-5)

    scatter_matrix(data,['a','b'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks fine. Depending on your system, scatterplot efficiency degrades around 10k to 100k points for pyqtgraph. If you really want to continue using pyqtgraph, all I can recommend is to subsample your data by 10x to 100x.

The amount of data you want to visualize almost requires GPU acceleration, so Galry is a good tool to use here. FYI, the developers of pyqtgraph, Galry, and a few other python graphics libraries are working together on VisPy, which is not quite ready for use, but should be a very good option in the future. PyQtGraph will also be using VisPy to provide GPU acceleration in the future.

Comment: Thank you for providing this information. I did come across VisPy and realized that its still at an early stage of development. Once that project matures I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Luke Does PyQtGraph now have GPU acceleration?

Comment: Not in the way I had predicted above, but there have been some dramatic performance improvements recently (I believe these use both the GPU and numba) to accelerate its graphics pipeline. I recommend testing out the latest version from github to see it it meets your needs.