# crashe PyQtGraph in python

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I created a code which receives in real time (every 1 second) temperature data (set temperature + temeparture read: in a text file), but the curve works fine in 2 days then from 3 days (200000 data approximately: 200000/3600 = 2.5 days) the curve crashes, I want to know is there a limit of data acquisitions? and I want to plot the curve in real time without any problem (30 days)

Here is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg


app = QtGui.QApplication([])
bytecount = 300   # This variable sets the number of bytes to read in
cnt = 0
XA = []
YA = []

p=pg.plot()
p.setWindowTitle('Courbe de Température (°C)')
p.setInteractive(True)
p.addLegend()
curve = p.plot(pen=(255,0,0), name="Consigne")
curve2 = p.plot(pen=(0,255,0), name="Actuelle")
data = [0]
data2 = [0]
data3 = [0]
LUE = 0
CONSIGNE = 0
STOP = 0



def update():


    global curve, data, curve2, data2, LUE, CONSIGNE,STOP,timer

    f = open("STOP.txt", "r")
    for line in f:
        STOP = line
    f.close()

    if float(STOP)==1:
        timer.stop()


    else:

        f = open("ValTempLue.txt", "r")
        for line in f:
            LUE = line
        f.close()

        f = open("ValTempConsi.txt", "r")
        for line in f:
            CONSIGNE = line
        f.close()


        X = float(CONSIGNE)
        Y = float(LUE)
        data.append(X)
        data2.append(Y)
        #xdata = np.array(data, dtype='float64')
        curve.setData(data)
        curve2.setData(data2)
        print(len(data))



    app.processEvents()

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(update)
timer.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the curve crashes"? Is there an error message? Or just the data is no good? Post some specifics about what exactly is happening and what you expect to happen.

Comment: no error message, the data is good, but the curve crashes after the plotting of several points (200,000 points: every one second I have a data to plot) just at the start the curve is good just after 2 days of data plotting every one second the curve crashes but on the 'run' tab of pycharm I saw the data on the console arriving 200000 and it remains to increment

Comment: I am not a pycharm user so I don't quite follow your explanation. So you're saying the curve is typically in a separate window, and that window crashes?

Comment: Maybe this related post could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993177/efficiently-plot-large-data-sets-with-pyqtgraph

Comment: I summarize my problem: at the beginning the interface works very well after 2 days the interface hangs (crashes) without having an error code, I think the problem of the saturation of the number of points to be displayed on the curve (Setpoint + read) so my question is whether there is a method so that the curve does not crash (knowing that I have declared 'data' and data2 'without limit).

Comment: The stackoverflow link I posted above might help. When you get to >200k data points, wouldn't it make sense to start sub-sampling?